# replace the existing plot and not create a new one

Tags: python, matplotlib

When the user input y value, I want the dashed line to be plotted on the same existing plot and not create a new plot. But it is creating a new plot. Could anyone please tell me how to update the existing plot. Below is the code

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Existing plot
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16], 'b-')  # Example plot

# Display the plot
plt.show()

# Ask for user input
y_value = float(input("Enter the y-value for the line: "))

# Add the user input line to the plot
plt.axhline(y=y_value, color='r', linestyle='--')

# Display the updated plot
plt.show()
```

I tried to `plt.clf()`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

## First answer, for regular python script

(see my update at the end for same in notebook)

The simpler method, starting from your code: use `plt.pause(0.1)`, not `plt.show()`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,4,3,7])
plt.pause(0.1)
y=int(input("y>"))
plt.axhline(y)
plt.show()
```

But you may also want to read about

- plt.ion()
- animate()
- updating data with setdata

`plt.clf()` is to clear the figure. The only relation with the interactive usage you are asking for, is that, now that you know how to add some new things to your plot, you may need to remove things also. `clf` removes everything. Giving you the "poor man animation" method, that is ploting, showing with `pause` rather than with `show`, and then clear the plot, and plot again.

## Update : jupyter notebook

For notebook, you need to tell matplotlib that you are using a notebook, so that it can create a kind of javascript "window" to behaves almost as a normal window.
And you need to force the draw manually, since it doesn't always work (sometimes, without explicit draw, you end with all the plot in the same figure, as you want, but only when the cell is finished, that the final result)

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

fig=plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,4,3,7])
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.pause(0.1)
y=int(input("y>"))
plt.axhline(y)
plt.show()
```

Note that you could do with only the redraw, and no pause. But because it depends on the version of jupyter, of matplotlib, on the context, etc., I am used to "belt and suspenders" approach for this kind of things. Any way, the `draw` cannot harm if it is useless, neither does the `pause` (but for the 100 ms lost, but since it is just before a human interaction, and human is the slowest part of the interaction even with this pause, it doesn't really matter. Besides, you can use 0.01 if you prefer). As is, this code works on all my computers — and more importantly on all my students computers with notebooks. And it also works as a python script (no notebook), but for the `%matplotlib notebook` declaration

Comment: Does `plt.pause(0.01)` always show the plot in its current state?

Comment: I guess it does: "If there is an active figure, it will be updated and displayed before the pause, and the GUI event loop (if any) will run during the pause." [link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pause.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. pausing 0.1 only pauses the appearance of the first plot by 0.1. But it still shows two plots. I would need to see the first plot first, input the value of y, and then add the line based on y to the existing plot, rather than creating a new plot of the y line.

Comment: @chrslg I hadn't heard about `%matplotlib notebook` before. I clearly don't use Jupyter notebooks very much.

Comment: it worked like a charm. adding %matplotlib notebook worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To make sure a new plot isn't created, you can make use of the ["explicit" API](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#api-interfaces) and call `plt.subplots`, which gives you a Figure and Axes object you can use to plot with. If you make use of those, you will ensure you're adding to the original plot. Note: this is possible using the "implicit" API using `fig = plt.figure()` and `ax = fig.gca()`, but I think the "explicit" formulation is clearer.

Since you most likely want the plot to be shown before the user inputs the y value to draw at, you can use `plt.pause(0.01)`, as [@chrslg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20037042/chrslg) suggests. According to the documentation of `plt.pause`,

> If there is an active figure, it will be updated and displayed before the pause, and the GUI event loop (if any) will run during the pause.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16], "b-")

# display the current plot immediately
plt.pause(0.01)

# add to earlier plot because we are now telling it which to draw to using ax
y_value = float(input("Enter the y-value for the line: "))
ax.axhline(y=y_value, color="r", linestyle="--")
fig.show()
```

To reiterate: by making use of the Axes object to plot, you ensure the proper plot is updated rather than creating a new one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using Jupyter. It says it is a non-GUI backend. Which IDE is best for this kind of execution?
Error: C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:17: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.

Comment: I use Spyder. Its easiest to get using Anaconda or miniconda.

Comment: But this can be done in a jupyter notebook if you use interactive mode. After your matplotlib import, add `%matplotlib` on a new line to make it interactive. You may also need `plt.ion()`. Then, instead of `fig.show()`, use `plt.pause(0.01)` again.

Comment: @SP but you should have specified that you use Jupyter. That is something else. With jupyter, it is a server-client architecture. So you cannot just update a window like this. Well, there are ways. But  it is very different, since, by default, each show (whether with `show`, `pause`, or even with nothing, since at the end of the cell it shows plot, generate an image (on "server" side) that is then displayed by the client.